# Submit based on ajax response causes loop, how to properly call native submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have a form where continuation of submit depends on ajax response.

```
    $('#restaurant_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchRestaurant(); // Checks if restaurant is already registered
    });
```

In `fetchRestaurant()`, when restaurant does not exist yet I call this to proceed:

```
$('#restaurant_form').submit();
```

but I'm having a loop where the event handler for submit seems to be triggered. How do I properly call the native submit?

Comment: Insufficient details to actually understand the core problem. Create a minimal snippet demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Details are sufficient Adam, you just dont get the point. I fully understand where he stuck.

Comment: Call `submit()` on the actual element, not on the jQuery wrapped object..

Comment: @PatrickEvans I moved implementation of fetchRestaurant to event handler of submit. In submit handler I have, `form = $(this)` and then called `form.submit()` on the response, it is still looping.

Comment: `$(this)` is still a jQuery wrapped object... you need to call submit on the actual form element, eg `this.submit()`

Comment: it's not working, isn't `this` referring to the the ajax when I call it inside the success: function(data){} ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use preventDefault method, you end in non submittable loop. Use return.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateRestaurant(this)">
  ...
</form>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function validateRestaurant (form) {
    $.get('fetchRestaurant.php')
     .then(function (restaurant) {
        if (restaurant.exists) form.submit()
      })
    return false
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It always proceed with the submit. It seems like there is a timeout for event handler because when I added an alert() and it had time to wait for the response, it works. But without the alert() it proceeds to the submit immediately.

Comment: If you set directly return false in callback, still allways proceed?

Comment: it goes to `else return false` first before response was received

Comment: @Waldermarlce `$.get()` is async you can't do a return from that

Comment: yeah, it proceeds with submit even though return is false.